# Missing at Random / Missing not at Random

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data, data-imputation

I plan a study where I predict variables with machine learning methods integrating data from multiple surveys. The questionnaires assessed with each survey slightly differ, so that I have a lot of missing values (e.g. Questionnaire 1 was assessed in survey 1,2,3, but not in survey 4).

My question is, do the *Missing at Random* assumption hold, if the different samples differ systematically in e.g. age? As far as I understood, loosely speaking, if e.g. age can predict the absence of values but is not related to the specific values itself (e.g. expression in a specific item), than the missing at random assumption and imputation is still valid. But in my case, they are probably low correlations between some questionnaire facets and age. Is this a problem if I plan to impute the missing values, using mean imputation or more sophisticated methods?

Greetings

Comment: If there are systematic differences, there is an issue of overlap and then it becomes a model specification issue. In other words, you do not know how some items in questionnaire 1 relate to other items in the same questionnaire, *for the age-group at survey 4*. The question is then whether this relationship can be extrapolated from the relationship in surveys 1,2 and 3. For instance, if the true model is linear, extrapolating how the relationships change as a function of age based on how it changed from survey 1 to 2, 2 to 3, is relatively straightforward.

Comment: Thank you! Concerning the extrapoltion, I would say yes. In survey 4, the age range is more narrow and this range is included in the other surveys, so I think extrapolating the relationship between age and the other variables should work. But isn't that something that would be implicitly done by using more sophisticated imputation methods, such as nearest neighbor imputation?